# how to check that element has focus in selenium webdriver using C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I Want to check whether element is focused or not? 
I tried

```
Assert.True(Selenium.IsElementPresent("id=txtemail:focus"));
```

and also so many commands but all displaying error that missing assembly reference
thanks!

Comment: This is missing a number of things. What does "in focus" mean? It has different meanings for different applications. Does it mean the user can see it? Does it mean that it's within the viewport of the screen? What errors are you getting? The missing assembly errors will be nothing to do with your assertions or how you are seeing if an element is "in focus", it means you've not set up the project correctly. Post the **entire** error, with it's **entire stack trace**.

Answer (score 0):

I started [with this post](http://blog.wedoqa.com/2011/07/selenium-how-to-check-if-an-element-has-focus/) and ended up with this extension method. The coordinates property seemed to be the best value to use. This could fail if there are 2 elements on top of each other, but you probably don't want that anyway.

```
/// <summary>
/// Does the current element have focus?
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">The element to test</param>
/// <returns>If the element is focused.</returns>
public static bool IsElementFocused(this RemoteWebElement element)
{
    var focusedElement = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)UITestFramework.Browsers.Browser.Driver).ExecuteScript("return document.activeElement;") as RemoteWebElement;
    return focusedElement != null && focusedElement.Coordinates.AuxiliaryLocator.ToString() == element.Coordinates.AuxiliaryLocator.ToString();
}
```